# Android Wear: disable gestures

Tags: android, wear-os, gesture

Recently Android Wear introduced gestures so the user can navigate between apps/notifications without using their finger.

I already had a working app but that kept being removed from the screen due to these gestures. I tried it with an app made by Google itself (Googlesamples-JumpingJack) This has the same problem.

The purpose of these app is to move. But these cause the gestures to trigger. How can I disable these as long as my app is on, so that the Activity stays on the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my understanding goes, you can (only?) disable gestures within the settings menu of the watch. I myself am struggling with disabling one or two specific gestures and so far found you can enable or disable them all. Haven't found anything on how to do this within your code, rather than within the settings.